# Submit Button Font - What is it? (browser default styles)

Tags: css, button, input, submit, fonts

I was wondering what is the default font is for `<input type=submit>` tags?

I am running Mac OS 10.6 with Firefox 3.6. But the font is the same for Safari 5 as well.

Pic of default styled input button is here: http://twitpic.com/2388tp

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lucida Grande. It's the default system font on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 3):

Probably defined by the default system font. Geneva or Lucida Grande, most likely the former.

Best way to check would be to say

```
.submit
{
    font-family: "Geneva";
}
```

Comment: Be warned that setting `font: "Geneva";` isn't good enough to override the font.. it must be `font-family`

Answer (score 0):

I found out it was **Lucida Grande**.